# Select text between brackets starting with ^{text to be selected} using regex

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Eg: sdadjaskdhas ^{sdassad ^{/frac{}{} s dcds &} dsdsadsa} ddsfsafdsfs

Answer should be: {sdassad ^{/frac{}{} s dcds &} dsdsadsa}

it should include any character between brackets

Comment: It is impossible to answer welll without knowing what programming language you are using for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backspace to escape the `^,{,}` characters as they belong to regex. `.*` to select any number of any characters.

Here is your answer: `\^\{.*\}`

EDIT:
You can use this regex [^\^]*\^{(\S*)} , print the match, trim the string. Loop over this you find all matches in a string.

Comment: The brackets can also be of any type ^{}, ^[], ^().  Please help

Comment: Not involving backslash in the output.     "\f" is not coming if searched on "abc ^{\frac{}} dsad"

Comment: Since the bracket can be of any type, you can blindly use .* to match any character.

Comment: What should be output for `abc ^{\frac{}} dsad` ?

`\frac{}` ?

Comment: I want to match string between parentheses (starting should be ^{ ).e.g.  'abc ^{\frac{}} dsadabc ^{\frac{}} dsad' should match two times and should return ['\frac{}', '\frac{}']

Comment: You can use this regex `[^\^]*\^\{(\S*)\}` , print the match, trim the string. Loop over this you find all matches in a string.

Comment: Thanks, This would do the job.

Comment: You're welcome. I will edit the answer with this one and you can mark it as answer.